# How to get class name by using id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

How to get the class name by using `id` in javascript?

```js
function interest(id) {
  var post_id = id;
  var class_name = id.className;
  alert(class_name);
}
```

```html
<span id="4" onclick="interest(this.id)" class="badge badge-secondary">
 Interested
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the HTML node put `onclick="interest(this)"` and then in the `onclick` handler you can get both the id and the className from the first argument.

```js
window.interest = function(node) {
    var id = node.id;
  var className = node.className;
  alert(id + " " + className);
}
```

```html
<span id="4" onclick="interest(this)" class="badge badge-secondary">
    Interested
</span>
```